# CSS changes when navigating from and back to Page - React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm building an Instagram clone. In doing so, I'm getting a very weird CSS behavior that I've not seen before.

Right now, I've got two pages: sign-up and login. The sign-up page has a link to the login page and vice versa. However, when I load the sign-up page for the first time (if I go directly to the route), it loads as I would expect in terms of the CSS design. However, when I click on the login link then back to the sign-up page, the CSS design changes. More specifically, my main-container width seems to change.

This is what I have so far:
***signup.js***

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
import logo from '../../images/logo.png'
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';

import Button from "../../components/button/Button"

import './signup.css'

export default function Signup() {

    const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({username: '', fullname: '', emailAddress: '', password: ''})

    function handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        setInputData(prevInputData => ({...prevInputData, [name]: value}))
    }

    return (
        <div className="main-container flex-center flex-column-direction">
            <div className="signup-container flex-center flex-column-direction">
                <img src={logo} alt="Logo"/>
                <form className="form flex-center flex-column-direction">
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        name="username"
                        value={inputData.username}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        className="form-input"
                    />
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Full Name"
                        name="fullname"
                        value={inputData.fullname}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        className="form-input"
                    />
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Email Address"
                        name="emailAddress"
                        value={inputData.emailAddress}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        className="form-input"
                    />
                    <input 
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        name="password"
                        value={inputData.password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        className="form-input"
                    />
                </form>
                <Button label="Sign up" />
            </div>
            <div className="login-container flex-center">
                <p>Have an account? <Link to={ROUTES.LOGIN} style={{color: 'blue'}}>Log in</Link></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the associated CSS: ***signup.css***

```
.flex-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-column-direction {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 35%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.signup-container {
    border: 0.1px solid #ebeff0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.form {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0.3px solid #ebeff0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #f2fcff;
}

.login-container {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 0.3px solid #ebeff0;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Like I said before, when I navigate from and back to this page, my `main-container` width seems to change on its own (see below screenshots). If I refresh the page (on the browser), it goes back to what I would expect (i.e. what's in the CSS file - 35%).

Going to signup page directly:
[image]

Then clicking on the "login" page then going back to the signup page (through a link on the login page) gives me this:
[image]

As you can see, the width of the form has changed without modifying any parameters in the CSS.

Also, I'm actually getting almost the exact same behavior if I reverse the steps. So if I go to the login page directly then navigate to to the sign up page and back to the login, it changes the CSS width of my container in the login page. I'm hoping the reason is the same as my question above but I'll find that out through help.

Comment: That's because the css is not scoped but global so if you have the same class in 2 components the last one overrides the first one. This why [css-modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/#why-should-we-use-css-modules) invented :)

Comment: That's what happens when you change global classes. Either scope each component with a unique css class or use unique css classes for each element using BEM for example.

Comment: @MoshFeu but I've got my CSS files in two different locations and for each .js file, I'm only importing it's corresponding CSS. For example, in `signup.js`, I'm only doing `import './signup.css'` while in `login.js` I'm doing the same like `import './login.css'`. Why would there be an overlap in this case and what would the solution here be? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with css-modules so perhaps I have to take a look at that too.

Comment: @Melchia please see my above comment. I believe I've scoped each component with its unique css class.

Comment: Unlike regular web apps, React (as any other SPA frameworks) doesn't load the **entire** html but **replace** only the relevant tags inside the body. When the browser loads one component's css it doesn't "forget" it so when the user navigates and the component been replaced, the styles are still there. In order to solve that, in need to "scope" the css (imagine both of the forms are at the same page but you want the form width to be different), and give the parent a different class name.

Comment: Thank you @MoshFeu. I have renamed each of the classes to reflect different names and that's worked. If you'd like to put in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All css files in react are merged into one final file, so if you have login.css inside your Login component with .main-container selector it can override .main-container from signup.css file.

You should use unique selectors for components or add additional classes only for properties which are different. E.g:

```css
.main-container {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-container__signup {
    width: 35%;
}

.main-container__login {
    width: 50%;
}
```